# Monad Transformer for Halogen Components

Tags: monad-transformers, purescript, halogen

I'm trying to figure out in which way I can use a transformer on the monad that a [Halogen](https://github.com/slamdata/purescript-halogen) component contains.

I'd like to extend the [intro example](https://github.com/slamdata/purescript-halogen/blob/a9708c42d023fcc567e83bf3a43708ab73f8efca/examples/intro/src/Main.purs) by a ReaderT that carries a Config record which in this case could be used to make the strings configurable, but I'm a lost when it comes to putting it all together.

Let's say we define our Config like this:

```
-- | Global configuration
newtype Config = Config { toggleText :: String
                        , onText :: String
                        , offText :: String
                        }
```

Our `ui` function would then turn from

`forall m eff. (Monad m) => Component m Input Input`

to

`forall m (Monad m) => Component (ReaderT Config m) Input Input`.

To evaluate our main function, we'd then use `hoistComponent` to turn it back into its previous form:

```
main = do
  let config = Config { toggleText: "Toggle Button"
                      , onText: "On"
                      , offText: "Off"
                      }
  Tuple node _ <- runUI $ hoistComponent (runReaderT config) ui
  appendToBody node
```

I'm not sure if this even makes sense so far, but pretending that it does, the next step is where I'm struggling. In an ideal world, my ui function would allow me to do something like this:

```
ui :: forall m eff. (Monad m) => Component (ReaderT Config m) Input Input
ui = render <$> stateful (State { on: false }) update
  where
  render :: State -> H.HTML (ReaderT Config m Input)
  render (State s) = do
    (Config conf) <- ask
    return $ H.div_ [ H.h1_ [ H.text conf.toggleText ]
                    , H.button [ A.onClick (A.input_ ToggleState) ]
                               [ H.text (if s.on then conf.onText else conf.offText) ]
                    ]

  update :: State -> Input -> State
  update (State s) ToggleState = State { on: not s.on }
```

But I end up with a long chain of unification errors and don't know where to start. Obviously, the inner use of `ask` cannot work like this, because I'd need to lift it into the HTML context, but I'm not even sure if that's possible.

It would be great if someone could guide my through the types here and tell me if that general approach is sensible. A full (non-compiling) example is [on GitHub](https://github.com/passy/purescript-halogen-intro-config/blob/a4ba9ce1be34ea8d07263b142ecf8be0e60b0304/src/Main.purs). I18n should only serve as a simple example use of the Reader here.

Answer (score 3):

The monad `m` is the monad for event handlers. The `HTML` document itself would not have access to the configuration in your `Reader` monad.

You would use `Reader` if you wanted your event handlers to have access to some configuration object, and you would have to replace the use of `A.input_` with an action in the `Reader` monad.

To do what you want to do, you probably want something more like `MonadReader Config m => m (Component _ _ _)`, where the component itself depends on the configuration.

Comment: Thanks Phil, that clears up one of the misconceptions I had about the event handler and the use case of the inner monad. If I want to use a `MonadReader` over the Config object, would I then have to implement `instance SF1ReaderT :: (Monad m) => MonadReader r (SF1 req) where ...`?

Comment: Well, crucially, `SF1` isn't a `Monad` because of how its `Apply` instance works. If you want to use a configuration object with the signal function, I would just pass it as an argument honestly.

Comment: That would explain what the `r13` in `No instance found for Prelude.Monad r13` referred to. Thanks for being so patient, I think I've been trying to learn too many things at once here. I'll go with passing it on manually for now. :)